# Multiple Request with Flask API and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cors, flask-restful

Below is the request that I did. Everything works except when I try the `put /stats-batch` which shows this error. I don't know what is the `options` that is being displayed, I only noticed it today.

The `/stats-batch` also just prints hello when access

```
27.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:20:46] "OPTIONS /user HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:20:46] "POST /user HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:20:48] "OPTIONS /product HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:20:48] "GET /product HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:20:48] "OPTIONS /new-batch HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:20:48] "GET /new-batch HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:21:21] "OPTIONS /new-batch HTTP/1.1" 200 -
oks
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:21:21] "PUT /new-batch HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:21:21] "GET /new-batch HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:21:43] "OPTIONS /stats-batch HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2021 16:21:44] "PUT /stats-batch HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Allen\santeh\env\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
.......
.......
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

I call this functions with a button click using `axios` like this. `config` has the `authorization header` just like all the other request

```
const startBatch = async () => {
  const status = 'start'

  await axios
    .put('http://127.0.0.1:5000/stats-batch', status, config)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

The console shows the `error` that `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource`.

I also have `flask_cors` installed and the other axios request is working. I don't know what cause this error if its the backend or the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see an issue; "/new-batch" endpoint is throwing 500 exceptions, which could be related to "Object of type function is not JSON serializable".

Based on the description / Error "**No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource**" message what I understand is

1. CORS configuration has been missed for PUT VERB.
   Because you wrote that rest of the endpoints work without issues, only PUT on this specific "/new-batch" endpoint fails.

**Options:** In CORS, a preflight request is sent with the OPTIONS method so that the server can respond if it is acceptable to send the request.

URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

[image]